# React localhost page shows a blank white-page,nothing is showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

here are my codes, I don't know what I  am doing wrong.

I have used a website called robohash which let us generate random robot image no matter what text I include, for example, robohash.org/test (which I have used in my code).

Also, the command prompt shows that it has been compiled with no errors or warnings.

```js
// Card.js

import React from 'react';
const Card = () => {
 
 return (
  <div className = 'tc bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5'>
   <img alt='robots' src='https://robohash.org/test' /> 
   <div>
    <h2> Jane Doe </h2>
    <p> Jannythemanny@gmail.com </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 );
}

export default Card;
```

```js
// robot.js file


export const robots = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Leanne Graham',
    username: 'Bret',
    email: 'Sincere@april.biz'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ervin Howell',
    username: 'Antonette',
    email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Clementine Bauch',
    username: 'Samantha',
    email: 'Nathan@yesenia.net'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Patricia Lebsack',
    username: 'Karianne',
    email: 'Julianne.OConner@kory.org'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Chelsey Dietrich',
    username: 'Kamren',
    email: 'Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Mrs. Dennis Schulist',
    username: 'Leopoldo_Corkery',
    email: 'Karley_Dach@jasper.info'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Kurtis Weissnat',
    username: 'Elwyn.Skiles',
    email: 'Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Nicholas Runolfsdottir V',
    username: 'Maxime_Nienow',
    email: 'Sherwood@rosamond.me'
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Glenna Reichert',
    username: 'Delphine',
    email: 'Chaim_McDermott@dana.io'
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Clementina DuBuque',
    username: 'Moriah.Stanton',
    email: 'Rey.Padberg@karina.biz'
  }
];
```

```js
//imdex.js file

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import card from './Card';
import 'tachyons';
import { robots } from './robots';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
     <card id={robots[0].id} name={robots[0].name} email={robots[0].email} />
     <card id={robots[1].id} name={robots[1].name} email={robots[1].email} />
     <card id={robots[2].id} name={robots[2].name} email={robots[2].email} />
     
    </div>
, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the reason: `Card` imported as `card`, it **has to be uppercased!**

```
<card id={robots[0].id} name={robots[0].name} email={robots[0].email} />
```

`<Card />` gets props (id, name, email) but they aren't used inside Card component.

Why cards are rendered manually/hardcoded? Where is a List component, loop rendering ... find and learn from better tutorials.

Comment: even i added <h2>{props}</h2>   and <p>{props}</p>    still there is a blank white page. I dont know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: import css?? too many strange things/possible errors; show your html - minimum parts with js and `<div id="root"></div>`   .... or recreate this in stackblitz

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked! It was an issue with upper-lower cases and also with the import of my card.js

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have an index.html contain `<div id="root"></div>`. Also you can try add key value to your cards. And can you add browser console output? I can't comment to post, so I wrote here.

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked ! It was issue with upper-lower cases and also with import of my card.js